# How to achieve visual inheritance in C# and VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-inheritance

I'm using VS2010 and WinForms, and needs lots of forms for creating/updating data entities.  How can I go about creating a base form from which to inherit (Cancel and OK buttons, entity parameters, etc)?

Comment: Cancel and OK buttons sound like part of the UI and shouldn't have anything to do with entity framework. Do you think you can explain the problem better?

Comment: He's saying that he's building a UI around an EF-based application and will need a lot of similar UI dialogs.  E.g. can he reuse portions of various forms (to include things like Cancel and OK buttons, along with, I'm sure, logic around save/delete/add, etc.)

Comment: Well explained Robaticus; yes, I just want to avoid writing dozens of "OnClickOK()" code and such, so I just need to write the custom 'per entity class' display and editing code.

Comment: edit:  removed EF reference, added WinForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheritance in graphical interfaces (especially forms) is not the easiest thing to achieve. You would probably be better off using reusable [user controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx).

It has nothing to do with Entity Framework, but more with the kind of graphical library you're using (assuming Windows Forms, but could be WPF or even WebForms).

Comment: Apparently my mention of EF is distracting.  You are right, it has nothing to do with EF.  I'm using Windows Forms, have done almost nothing with UI for years, but remembered (vaguely) visual inheritance being touted years past, probably in VB.